# Random numbered files using win7 in bat file

Tags: batch, batch-file, file-management

I have a mp3 player that has a poorly designed hard coded random generator for shuffling songs. Every time I turn it on, it plays the same sequence (5-22-3-150-75-86... etc) In order to hear a larger variety I want to be able to periodically randomize the file names on the usb stick and alter the files position in the directory listing.

I am trying to rename all file names in a sub-directory to a random number. This is what I have been trying but it does not work. For some reason *%num% is blank in the new file name*.

```
1|    for %%A in (*.mp3) DO (
2|    set /A num=%RANDOM%*100/32768+1
3|    ren "%%A" %num%.mp3
4|    )
5|    pause
```

*(Line numbers added for clarity during this discussion)*

The output for each file is shown below.

> D:\music_playlists\pop-mix [25gb]>(
>   set /A num=13621*100/32768+1
>   ren "Country-132.mp3" **.mp3**
>   )
>  
>   A duplicate file name exists, or the file
>   cannot be found.

As you can see the ***%NUM% is not being expanded to a file name on line #3***...

### What do I need to do?

update - not sure exactly what was going on but this seems to work even though the echo shows a blank field

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%A IN (*.mp3) DO (
SET  /A NUM=!RANDOM!
echo !NUM!
REN "%%A" !NUM!.mp3
)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [enabling delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and changing the `%` signs used with `RANDOM` and `NUM` to `!` points:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%A IN (*.mp3) DO (
SET /A NUM=!RANDOM!*100/32768+1
REN "%%A" !NUM!.mp3
)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

---

If the random number has already been chosen, does any file have the same name? Thus, will fail

In general, yes, so in these situations, you will need to get another random number to rename the file with a unique name/number.

---

May I suggest taking the range of two decimal places further, evasively decreasing the likelihood of repetition when renaming files?

---

```bash
@echo Off && SetLocaL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f delims^=* %%i in =;(
      'dir /on /a:-d /b "*.mp3"'
    =;) do call %:^) "%%~dpi" "%%~nxi"

endlocal && goto :eof || exit /b 0 

%:^)
for /f %%f in =;(
      'set /a _num^=!random!*1000/32768+1'
    =;) do set "_num=100%%~f"

if not exist "%~1!_num:~-4!.mp3" =;(
     ren "%~1%~2" "!_num:~-4!.mp3"
     exit /b =;) else goto %:^)
```

Comment: Why do you use the `:^)` characters for the routine label?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT  so, for short and nice options...